# How to Assign one variable to another variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a small confusion on assigning variable to another variable . I have a code which takes value in a filter variable as

```
filter = '(uid=tommy)'
```

I am trying to pass `tommy` via command line using

```
user_id = sys.argv[1:]
print user_id
filter = '(uid=user_id)'
```

But of-course this doesn't replace the variable **user_id**  , how can i achieve this ??

Comment: `filter = '(uid={})'.format(user_id)`

Comment: @xnx thanks man ! works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need string `format` function:

```
user_id = "tommy"
filter = '(uid={})'.format(user_id)
print(filter)
# (uid=tommy)
```